# Given arbitrary integers of $K$ and $M$, can deciding $2^K$ + $M$ is a prime be in $P$?

Tags: polynomial-time, number-theory

Given arbitrary integers of $K$ and $M$, is $2^K$ + $M$ a prime?

```
K = int(input('enter exponent K: '))
M = int(input('enter integer for M: '))

if AKS.Primality(2**K + M) == True:
    OUTPUT 'yes'
else:
    OUTPUT 'no'
```

I am not knowledgeable enough in number theory or any other field of mathematics to know the answer to this question.

### Question

Is there a polynomial-time algorithm for this decision problem?

Comment: I've been coming up with decision problems that don't seem to have a known efficient algorithm. This is one of them!

Comment: Purposely done to take both $2^n$ time and space. Perhaps there is a clever way to look at the numbers and be able to decide without calculating $2^K$. Thus allowing a $P$ algorithm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean "polynomial in the size of the binary representation of K and M", then it is extremely unlikely, but proving that it is impossible will also be very difficult.

There are polynomial time algorithms for checking primality, but they would be applied to a number whose size is K, which is a lot bigger than checking a number whose size is the same as the size of K.

Comment: How about a $PSPACE$ algorithm? It seems equally unlikely. Because of $2^K$ has $K$ 0-bits in the binary representation.

Comment: @TravisWells See [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397576900244).

Comment: Turn this into a halting problem. Will this algorithim return yes? Can only take 2^n space. Because of the K 0-bits. I am onto something

Comment: I mean when K and M are given inputs for this halting problem.